# Where should server logs be kept?

Tags: django, nginx, logging, server, supervisord

I have a django webapp where lots of functions like online presence,chat messaging and other real time operations are going on.This is logging a lot of data in my daphne.log file. To give you an idea, within 5 minutes daphne.log file reached the size of 100kb when i am the sole person accessing the app.Certainly the daphne.log file will become huge when it will serve thousand of visitors per day. This will consume a lot of memory on my server.What should be the best approach to manage this kind of situation?

My thought is to have a some sort of program that will keep clearing daphne.log file in regular intervals but this nullifies the purpose of logs.

daphne.log file is present at

```
/home/user/django_project/logs/daphne.log
```

**What should i do if i want to retain logs?**

P.S: I have deployed my django app using Supervisor + Nginx + Postgresql + Daphne.

Comment: You can setup a cron job to send the log file to AWS S3 buckets on regular intervals, say once a week or so. This way you can save on your disk space.

Comment: @AmanGarg Thank you i will look into this.